# javascript vs Java EE / PHP / other web development apps

Tags: javascript

I am wondering in what situations would it be better to use javascript instead of Java EE/PHP/others? Because before I only know javascript, then when I learned Java EE/PHP, I never use javascript anymore because I do everything in Java EE or PHP.

I hope you can enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript tends to be on the client (browser), even though some is starting to appear on the server side (node.js, for instance).

The others (PHP, Java EE, ASP.NET, JSP and more) are server side, mostly used for heavy processing, accessing databases etc... They generate HTML (and sometimes javascript) that is sent to the browser.

Comment: i am a little bit confused.. so when to use javascript? can you give me an example. thank you.

Comment: @newbie - When you want to change things _in_ the browser without going back to the server.

Comment: @newbie - hiding data when a user clicks on a button.

Comment: ah okay. hehehe.. I'm still confused. Anyway, thank you. I'll just read more about these concepts. I guess I need I just to read more!! I'm still clueless. :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and stuff like PHP is something completely different. JavaScript is clientside whereas PHP is sererside. Clientside code is executed by the site's viewer while serverside code is executed on the server and sends the results to the client. Serverside is also suited for accessing databases and other stored data.

You should use serverside code to generate your webpage to show the user, and clientside code such as JavaScript to give the users a more interactive experience.

Comment: @TVK-, can you give me an example please. Thank you.

Comment: For example, if you got data in your database, you can use PHP's `mysql_query()` to get that data and print it which will then be sent to the client. If on the client side you want to access some data, you can use JavaScript's AJAX functions (client side) to ask the server side (PHP) to get that data. After PHP generates it and sends it back to the client side, JavaScript can then handle it again. This is how adding comments on Stack Overflow works, for example.

Comment: @TVK- but does html forms can handle it also??

Comment: @TVK- i'm still confused. Anyway. Thank you. I'll just read more about this things. God Bless!

Comment: @TVK "JavaScript is clientside" -1 for not mentioning node.js

Comment: @newbie the server is for _creating_ the page. The client is for _changing_ the page after it's made.